# How to seek an academic mentor?

Tags: mentoring

I am a junior academic who is seeking an academic mentor to shape my career and have a stronger impact on the student and research community. What would be the best way to go about seeking a mentor?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of junior are you? Did you just start your Bachelors, are you a recently appointed faculty member,...?